# Git how to checkout a commit of a branch

Tags: git

How can I check out a commit version of a branch in `git`?

For example, my branch, `Dev`, has a commit `ad4f43af43e`. How can I check out that commit? Not just a single file, but a whole branch.

I searched online and found: `git checkout <commit>`, but it didn't specify branch name

Comment: A branch is just a pointer to a commit. Checkout the commit by its SHA1, then you make your HEAD point to that commit directly. I recommend you to read https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Branching-Branches-in-a-Nutshell

Answer (score 65):

```
git checkout <hash>         # non named commit
git checkout <branch_name>  # named commit
```

The two lines above will place the `HEAD` pointer on the given commit. You should know that a branch name is a commit, except it can evolve if a new commit is added when you're on that branch.

If you want to place your branch `Dev` on the commit `ad4f43af43e` you can do this

```
git branch -f Dev ad4f43af43e
```

Be careful! This is dangerous because you may lose commits.

Comment: What about if you want to checkout a specific file, on a specific hash, of another branch? E.g. iw ant to check out the contents of a single file from a particular hash on another branch, into my current working branch?

Comment: @Chuck not entirely sure, but this might help you: https://jasonrudolph.com/blog/2009/02/25/git-tip-how-to-merge-specific-files-from-another-branch/

Answer (score 51):

If you're looking to branch out from a specific commit of a branch, first be sure you are in the branch,

```
git checkout dev
```

Now I want to checkout a specific commit 123654 from the dev branch to a new branch while keeping the head on main branch.

```
git checkout -b new-branch 123654
```

Comment: This works nicely, but the switch happens, and so the HEAD will be `new-branch`.

Comment: You don't need to checkout `dev` before checking out 123456.

Answer (score 10):

You can `checkout` to the `commit-sha` then, create a new branch (say, `feature`) from that commit.

```
$ git checkout <commit>
$ git checkout -b feature    # create a new branch named `feature` from the commit


# if you want to replace the current branch (say 'develop') with new created branch ('feature') 
$ git branch -D develop     # delete the local 'develop' branch
$ git checkout -b develop   # create a new 'develop' branch from 'feature' branch
```

Comment: when you say create branch 'feature', the branch is in the remote or local ?

Comment: @user1615666: *all* Git branches are local. (Even your "remote-tracking branches", like `origin/master`, are actually local! They're just automatically *updated* to match `origin` when you run `git fetch`.  Think of `fetch` as "Tell my Git to call up another Git over the Internet-phone, and get any updates that other Git has for my Git." Meanwhile `git push` is "have my Git call up that same other Git, but instead of *getting* things, *give* them things and ask that they update their branches.")