# git: Address a commit inside a branch?

Tags: git

Up to now I know two ways to address a commit in git:

- via commit-hash
- via name of a branch

Is there a way to address a commit-hash inside an existing branch?

If I do checkout a commit-hash then I am not on a branch.

If I checkout a branch, then I always get to the latest commit of this branch.

How to address a commit inside a branch?

Comment: Please read [ask] and share your research. If you checkout a specific commit that's not the tip of a branch, then you're in detached head state. You can successively create a _new_ branch. Is that what you want? If not, then what do you want and what have you tried?

Comment: See [Fix a Git detached head?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10228760/fix-a-git-detached-head), [Git how to checkout a commit of a branch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42159715/git-how-to-checkout-a-commit-of-a-branch), and so on.

Comment: The question doesn't make sense. Rather than just dismiss the answer you have, can you clarify what it is you are trying to do (ie. why is ending up in a detached head state undesirable for what you want to achieve)? Maybe you want to reset a branch to a specific commit, or maybe you're hoping you could checkout a branch using a commit hash instead of a name, and we could explain why you can't do that?

Answer (score 0):

Use [`git branch <new-branch-name> <commit-hash>`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-branch) to create a new branch named `<new-branch-name>` that starts on the commit identified by `<commit-hash>`. You can then [`git checkout <new-branch-name>`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-checkout) to start working on it.

Or you can combine the two commands above into [a single command that does both operations](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-checkout#git-checkout-emgitcheckoutem-b-Bltnewbranchgtltstartpointgt) in one step:

```
git checkout -b <new-branch-name> <commit-hash>
```

Read more about [`git checkout`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-checkout) and [`git branch`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-branch). Also, somehow related to a part of your question is the documentation page that explains [the various ways to specify a Git revision or a range of revisions](https://git-scm.com/docs/revisions).

Comment: I want to checkout an existing branch.

Comment: A branch is a pointer to a commit. If you checkout a commit directly you get a [detached HEAD](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitglossary#gitglossary-aiddefdetachedHEADadetachedHEAD). Do you need to modify a past commit?

Answer (score 0):

If you checkout a specific commit, you are not on a branch, and it wouldn't mean anything for you to be on a branch. It is not clear what you are actually trying to achieve.

One thing you can do, is create a new branch at the commit, and switch to that branch:

```
$ git branch my-new-branch <commit-hash>
$ git checkout my-new-branch
```

That would make your commit the head of a new branch and have it checked out.

Commits in git form a tree, and a branch is nothing more than a label pointing to one of those commits. A commit could be part of any number of branches, and in many situations it doesn't make sense to think of commits as belonging to a branch.

Comment: I want to checkout an existing branch.

Comment: @guettli But you said you want to check out a specific commit. You can either check out a commit or a branch - what you're asking doesn't have any meaning. Perhaps if you explained why, or what you were trying to do, we might be able to help you?